# mysql in dot net core (pomelo mysql provider) - Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am having problems using .Net Core (3.1) with Mysql (provider Pomelo.mysql 3.1.1).
I have a really basic function (just getall records from a table, a one-line function) but for some reason I always get the ObjectDisposedException with all the stack trace happening in Pomelo Provider.
Does anyone know what could be causing this?

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
      Object name: 'MySqlConnection'.
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.VerifyNotDisposed() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 707
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_Session() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 480
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ICancellableCommandExtensions.ResetCommandTimeout(ICancellableCommand command) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ICancellableCommand.cs:line 42
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 261
```

The init code is:

```
            services
                .AddDbContextPool<DeviceDbContext>(o => o
                    .UseMySql(connectionString, o => o
                        .ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 19), ServerType.MySql))
                        .MigrationsAssembly(typeof(DeviceDbContext).Assembly.GetName().Name)
                        .EnableRetryOnFailure()))
                .AddHostedService<MigrationsHostedService<DeviceDbContext>>()
                .AddHealthChecks()
                .AddMySql(connectionString, "mysql");
return services;
```

and then later its just

```
services.AddDbContext();
```

usage later then is rather simple:

```
private readonly DeviceDbContextdbContext;

        public DeviceEntityFrameworkRepository(DeviceDbContext dbContext)
        {
            EnsureArg.IsNotNull(dbContext, nameof(dbContext));
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Device>> FindAllDevicesAsync()
            => await this.dbContext.Set<Device>().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

and the full exception stack is

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
      Object name: 'MySqlConnection'.
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.VerifyNotDisposed() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 707
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.get_Session() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line 480
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ICancellableCommandExtensions.ResetCommandTimeout(ICancellableCommand command) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ICancellableCommand.cs:line 42
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 261
         at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementationAsync[TState,TResult](Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, TState state, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
```

Comment: Can we get some code?  How are you setting up your DI (assuming you are using it)?  How are you using the context?

Comment: Can you paste the full exception call stack? What is your code when the exception happens?

Comment: Until you give us the code that instantiates the database connection and how it's being used, we really can't help you.

Comment: Edited the question with those details, couldn't add it as a comment

Comment: The exception call stack still doesn't include any of your code. Are you saving an `IEnumerable<>` value and accessing it after the database connection has been closed? That might cause this error.

Comment: no, I'm just loading the values, the FindAny function is all that its called. and that exception stack is all i get, literally no mention of any of my code, that's what i don't understand

Comment: You're not using Blazor Components, are you? A very similar call stack was posted here: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/997 
Otherwise, you might want to open an issue on that repo and see if the developers have any insight into the bug.

Comment: no blazor, this time specifically this is used in a hosted service in a normal webapi

Answer (score 0):

> The init code is:
>
> ```
>             services
>                 .AddDbContextPool<DeviceDbContext>(o => o
>                     .UseMySql(connectionString, o => o
>                         .ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 19), ServerType.MySql))
>                         .MigrationsAssembly(typeof(DeviceDbContext).Assembly.GetName().Name)
>                         .EnableRetryOnFailure()))
>                 .AddHostedService<MigrationsHostedService<DeviceDbContext>>()
>                 .AddHealthChecks()
>                 .AddMySql(connectionString, "mysql");
> return services;
> ```
>
> and then later its just
>
> ```
> services.AddDbContext();
> ```

Sounds like you are instantiating *two* `DbContext`s. You might want to use either `AddDbContextPool()` or `AddDbContext()`, but not both at the same time.

For testing purposes, start with just using `AddDbContext()` and see, whether you still prematurely dispose the context.

If you want to, you can also post/upload your full project, so we can take a close look at what's exactly wrong with your code.